# Para que serve "Helper" no Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Por favor explicar para serve `Helper` no Asp.Net MVC.

Vejo muitos exemplos que contém `Helper`. Não faço mínima ideia o que é **Helper**.

E como criar Helper ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Por favor explicar para serve Helper no Asp.Net MVC.

***Helper*** é uma classe estática, fora do grupo de *Controllers*, que possui lógica replicável para todo o restante do sistema.

Por "lógica replicável", é toda e qualquer lógica que é usada em dois ou mais lugares do sistema. [Há vários exemplos aqui no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+%5Basp.net-mvc%5D+helper).

Alguns exemplos de *Helpers* comuns:

- Consumo e tratamento de dados de *web services*;
- Criação de arquivos do Word, Excel etc.;
- Geração de links em *Views* Razor ([`HtmlHelper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx), [`UrlHelper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx)).

> E como criar Helper?

Basicamente, como uma classe estática comum, em um *namespace* próprio para isso. Por exemplo:

```
namespace MeuProjeto.Helpers
{
    public static class MeuHelper
    {
        public static String MetodoDoHelper1() { ... }
        public static int MetodoDoHelper2() { ... }
        public static void MetodoDoHelper3() { ... }
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
var retornoString = MeuHelper.MetodoDoHelper1();
var retornoInt = MeuHelper.MetodoDoHelper2();
MeuHelper.MetodoDoHelper3(); // pode não retornar valor, se for o caso.
```

Comment: Me ajudou muito, obrigado !

Comment: Confesso que uma pergunta como esta estava faltando mesmo. Espero ter ajudado :)